# Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: [] Error is in expression '{!edit}' [[[[[[

Tags: salesforce

when i update my existing data with visualforce page , i got thi error

Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []
Error is in expression '{!edit}' in page contract_object: Class.ContractController.edit: line 28, column 1

An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

```
please complite my code without error 

My Visual force Code is 

<apex:page Controller="ContractController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contract Form">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:selectList size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!contactlist}">
                    </apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.Name}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.First_Name__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.Last_Name__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.Phone_Number__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.Address__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.Email__c}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                    <apex:commandLink value="Edit" action="{!edit}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>


my controller code 
public class ContractController {
    public List<Contract__c> ContractTemp = new List<Contract__c>();
        public List<SelectOption> contactlist
    {
        get
        {
            ContractTemp = [Select Id,Name from contract__c];
            contactlist = new List<SelectOption>();
            for(Contract__c con : ContractTemp)
            {
                contactlist.add(new SelectOption(con.Id, con.Name));
            }
            return contactlist;
        }
        set;
    }
    public ContractController() {
        conObj = new Contract__c();
    }

    public Contract__c conObj {get; set;}
    
    public void save() {
        insert conObj;
    }
    public void edit() {
        
        update conObj;
    }
}
```